# Strange profiler results

Tags: java, performance

I just tried to profile a relativly simple java program using jvisualvm. The results were somewhat strange: A small 4-line method has the most self time, significantly more than any other method!

```
public class Hub
    public void clock() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cogs.length; i++) {
            cogs[i].clock(cnt, i, this);
        }
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Note: cogs.length is 8 in this case!

This is strange, as the Cog.clock method is considerably larger! The only plausible explanation i could come up with is the fact that most (in this case 6 of 8) Cog objects will be in a "stopped" state, which is catched like this:

```
public class Cog
    public void clock(int cnt, int cogid, Hub hub) {
        if (state == State.STOP)
            return;
        //long code goes here
    }
}
```

But that shouldn't have THAT big of an impact! Here is a picture of proof:

[image]

Comment: How many times are you calling `clock()`? Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: I edited to clarify the difference between Hub.clock and Cog.clock. Basically, Hub.clock gets called in an endless loop, and that then calls clock on all Cog objects.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the profiler much. The measurement influences the execution and has many problems. If the total runtime is really just 10 ms, then you can forget it; the JVM needs more to optimize everything properly. If you don't run into speed problems, then you can just ignore it (thought I'm also curious what exactly is goind on here). Otherwise, do a longer measurement and post the results.

Comment: @maaartinus total runtime is 10 seconds, not 10 ms

Comment: I'm basically emulating a multi-core CPU in a very crude and fast way. Problem is that even when skipping all waitstates and most I/O hardware, it's not quite real-time, even when just 2 cores are running. Reducing the amount of cores makes it somewhat faster, even though the other 6 don't so anything!